# Speed of scroll by mousedrag in tmux

Tags: tmux, mouse, scrolling

I have gathered a quite nice .tmux.conf with mouse selection going to clipboard and everything. But one thing is left to be optimized. When I MouseDrag1Pane (I assume) to the border of a pane, in copy-mode, the pane scrolls inside the scrollback buffer as intended. But it does so very slowly. I was totally unable to find any clue about this particular parameter as most scroll topics are about wheel events, which I do not have any issues with.

The, afaik, relevant part of my list-key:

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDrag1Pane        select-pane \; send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDragEnd1Pane     send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i"
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi MouseDrag1Pane        select-pane \; send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane     send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i"
bind-key    -T root         MouseDrag1Pane        if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "if -Ft= \"#{pane_in_mode}\" \"copy-mode -M\" \"send-keys -M\"" "copy-mode -M"
bind-key    -T root         MouseDrag1Border      resize-pane -M
```

If needed I'll gladly provide the rest of my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the scrolling rate when selecting except by changing `WINDOW_COPY_DRAG_REPEAT_TIME` in window-copy.c and rebuilding tmux.

Comment: Brilliant, not exactly the most accessible option but works nicely.